# Query total value per product

Tags: sql

I have run the below query to get list of customers who purchased total quantity purchased per product given that price is > 100. However, I am having issue adding a column of Total Value per Product (TotalQuantityPurchased * Price):

```
SELECT name, count(product) as TotalQuantityPurchased, 
SUM(price) as PriceOver100
FROM [order] 
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(price)>100;
```

The below is the raw data:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
|  name   | product | price |
+---------+---------+-------+
| Kathy   | A       |     1 |
| Kathy   | B       |   150 |
| Kathy   | B       |   150 |
| Chung   | C       |   120 |
| Peter   | D       |    40 |
| Peter   | E       |   210 |
| Chris   | A       |     1 |
| Chris   | W       |    90 |
| William | A       |     1 |
| William | K       |    20 |
| William | K       |    20 |
| William | N       |   350 |
| Tina    | K       |   500 |
| Tina    | P       |   160 |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: update your question and show the expected  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

The price value seems related  to product not to name so you have issue multipling value with different group by level

you could

```
SELECT name, product, count(product) as TotalQuantityPurchased, count(product) * price sum_price
SUM(price) as PriceOver100
FROM [order] 
GROUP BY name, product 
HAVING SUM(price)>100;
```

and then

```
select  name, sum(TotalQuantityPurchased), sum(sum_price)
from (
    SELECT name, product, count(product) as TotalQuantityPurchased, count(product) * price sum_price
    SUM(price) as PriceOver100
    FROM [order] 
    GROUP BY name, product 
    HAVING SUM(price)>100; 

) t  
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your expected outcome, I think you could use the same query except you should group by both name and product to get Total Value per Product ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9fc5be/2))

```
SELECT name, product, count(product) as TotalQuantityPurchased, 
SUM(price) as PriceOver100
FROM [order]
GROUP BY name, product
HAVING SUM(price)>100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you need a list with customer and the total quantity of products this customer bought, in which each we will compute only products above the price of 100. In this case, the query should be:

```
SELECT name, 
       count(product) as TotalQuantityPurchased
FROM [order] 
WHERE price > 100
GROUP BY name
;
```

In this case, the output, considering the table you gave on the question, will be:

```
Name       TotalQuantityPurchased
Kathy      2
Chung      1
Peter      1
William    1
Tina       2
```

What you have done on the query from your question is: to count the total quantity of products purchased from customers that has already bought over the price of 100, considering the sum of all his purchases.